# how to remove password lock when Google keyboard is uninstalled

Tags: google-search

I was creating space by uninstalling some apps.by mistake I uninstalled Google keyboard and kept quite. After sometime security Password lock was locked.when I tried to open the password lock ,the key is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting a usb keyboard to your phone.